# Queue a NSMutableArray into a NString as a loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

If one had a `NSString` that needed a userid to be used as a URL for a request:

And one had a `NSMutableArray` that he wanted to Queue into the above call one at a time? So basically make 3 calls of `NSString` from the `NSMutableArray` .

One can check multiple UITableView cells and once completed I can index which cell rows were pushed. That is what userIDArray is used for now I want to make a call with the userID's I got back from userIDArray.

```
for (NSDictionary* userIDDict in userIDArray)
{   
    userIDArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //I put this line in my viewdidload
    NSNumber* userID = [userIDDict objectForKey:@"UserID"];
}
```

UserIDArray is the `NSMutableArray` .

This would be the `NSLog` from the `NSMutableArray` The Integer would be 1, 2 and 3.

```
UserID: 1
UserID: 2
UserID: 3
```

So in other words I would like to take the results from my `NSMultiTableArray` 1,2 and 3 to use within the `NSString` :

```
NSString *userProfile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/userid=1"];

NSString *userProfile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/userid=2"];

NSString *userProfile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/userid=3"];
```

So I would make the first call and wait for a result, and then the second and finally the third.

Can this be done? I have search this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276704/dispatch-queue-and-return-data) about Queues and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797354/nsmutablearray-within-nsstring) but I am unsure if those are what I need?

UserDetailViewController.h file:

```
@interface UserDetailViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate>{

long long expectedLength;
long long currentLength;
UITableView *userTableView;
NSIndexPath* checkedIndexPath;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *userIDJson;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *userIDDict;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath* checkedIndexPath;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *userIDArray;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger currentUserIndex;

@end
```

UserDetailViewController.m file:

```
@interface UserDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation UserDetailViewController
@synthesize userIDJson;
@synthesize userIDDict;
@synthesize checkedIndexPath;
@synthesize userIDArray;
@synthesize currentUserIndex;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

userIDArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
//return self.loadedSearches.count;
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return self.userIDJson.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
}

cell.textLabel.text = self.userIDJson[indexPath.row][@"UserName"];

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

if([self.checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *thisCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *userStringIndex = [self.userIDJson objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if (thisCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
{
    thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [userIDArray addObject:userStringIndex];
}
else
{
    thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [userIDArray removeObject:userStringIndex];

}

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

if (self.currentUserIndex < userIDArray.count) {

NSNumber* userID = [[userIDArray objectForIndex:currentUserIndex]objectForKey:@"UserID"];

//Make the actual request here, and assign the delegate.
NSString *userProfile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/userid=%@",userID];

self.currentUserIndex++;

NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:userProfile]];

NSString *userResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: userProfile];

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

userIDJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL 
                                            options:kNilOptions
                                              error:&error];
  }

 }

for (userIDDict in userIDArray)
{
    NSNumber* userID = [userIDDict objectForKey:@"UserID"];
    NSLog(@"%@", userID);
    NSArray* userName = [userIDDict objectForKey:@"UserName"]; 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by calling an `NSString`? Do you mean you're going to use that string as a URL, and make an Internet connection with it?

Comment: Yeah I have already set up my json stuff and made a NSURLConnection with it. I want to make 3 calls from my NSMultiTableArray result. So http://example.com/userid=1 , then make another call with 2 and 3 from the NSMultiTableArray.

Comment: But I might receive more than 3 UserID's in my array. My array is a result that I have parsed from a json result that was returned from another call into a NSDictionary that I made into plain text to use in my NSString.

Comment: Regrading your new code, what is `surveyID` used for? It's not used in the rest of the method. Also, why is the result of `JSONObjectWithData` assigned to `userIDArray`?

Comment: Sorry I copy and pasted the wrong code

Comment: You created `userID` but didn't use it. Change the line that creates `userProfile` to use `userID` instead of `currentUserdIndex`. Also, don't forget to add `self.currentUSerIndex++;` after tou create the URL. This should get the idea, you wanted to implement, done.

Comment: Sorry, your question is totally unintelligible.  It's not clear whether you're asking about queues or string formatting or doing network requests or NSArrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSURLConnection` can take a delegate through the constructor `initWithRequest:delegate:`. So you need the object that makes the calls conform to that protocol, I'll assume it's a `UIViewController`. You can use one of the required methods in the delegate to fire up the next request.

For example, assume you have property to indicate the current index.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger currentUserIndex;
```

Then in the place that will fire the first request, make the call for the first user. In some delegate method, say [`connectionDidFinishLoading:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/connectionDidFinishLoading%3a)

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    if (self.currentUserIndex < self.userIDArray.count) {
        NSNumber* userID = [[self.userIDArray objectAtIndex:self.currentUserIndex] objectForKey:@"UserID"];
        self.currentUserIndex++;
        //Make the actual request here, and assign the delegate.
    }
}
```

Of course, if your connection calls don't have to be synchronous, you can do it in an easier way.

Comment: Would there be a reason I would getting the error: no visible @interface for NSMutableArray declares the selector objectAtIndex when I declared the delegate method currentUserIndex?

Comment: This is a little bit weird. Are you sure you're calling `objectAtIndex:` right? You can update your answer with the new edit you made, so I can understand clearly the problem.

Comment: I updated my code and please forgive my stupidity as I am a noob at ios.

Comment: Am I calling ObjectAtIndex in my code above or can you not tell? because no matter what I do I still that dreaded error. :(

Comment: `objectAtIndex:` is a method of `NSArray`, so by extent it's a method of `NSMutableArray`. You may be getting this error, because you didn't pass the parameter. If the problem persists, you can post the whole class.

Comment: Somehow I feel that you didn't define the functionality of your application clearly. You can draw a flow chart or write some pseudo-code to organize your work. For example, **View appears -> retrive users -> reload data -> do some action when user selects a row**... Also please check my last comment on the question. Choose Project -> clean, and build the application.